# Relational algebra and mysql statement for some query

Tags: mysql

I have a problem that I am stock. The question is this. I have a table called product in my database. It has three attributes, product(maker char(50), model int, type char(50)). The type attribute has several types, pc, laptop, and printer. There are tables for pc, laptop, and printer but I dont think I need these tables to solve my question. The question is that I have to find a relational algebra representation and mysql statement to find those makers that sell laptop but not pc. How can I do this?

Comment: Maybe start by normalizing your database?

Comment: @BenM what do you mean by normalizing?? I am new to database system. thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as MySQL, this should find those makers that are associated with laptops but not pc's.

```
SELECT DISTINCT product.maker
FROM product
LEFT JOIN product AS pc_products
  ON product.maker = pc_products.maker
    AND pc_products.type = 'pc'
WHERE product.type = 'laptop'
  AND pc_products.maker IS NULL;
```